# vector<string> doesnt work when using seperate classes

Tags: c++, string, class, vector, ifstream

I have a txt file which has a rogue-like level
I load it like so:

```
void File::LoadLevel()
{

ifstream input_file;
input_file.open("Level_1.txt");
if (input_file.fail())
{
    perror("Level_1.txt");
}
while (input_file >> _level)
{
    _level_instance.push_back(_level);
}
}
```

variables:

```
string _level;
vector<string> _level_instance;
```

I print it out like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _level_instance.size(); i++)
{
    cout << _level_instance[i] << endl;
}
```

which works fine.

however I have a vector in another class as well and i use a getter like this:

```
vector<string>GetlevelData(){ return _level_data; }
```

and I change the LoadLevel() from this:

```
_level_instance.push_back(_level);
```

to this:

```
    Level Lvl;
    Lvl.GetLevelData().pushback(_level);
```

I make an method in 'Level' class which prints it out to the screen same as before
it compiles but it doesnt print out anything why?

By the way in the `int main()` neccesary methods are executed which is `OpenLevel()` from `File` class and `Print()` from  `Level` class

EDIT:

passing it &by reference didnt work
here are both methods in Level.h:

```
void SetLevelData(const std::string &string) {
    _level_data.push_back(string);
}
//Getters
vector<string>& GetlevelData(){ return _level_data; }
```

in File.cpp:

```
void File::LoadLevel()
{

ifstream input_file;
Level lvl;
input_file.open("Level_1.txt");
if (input_file.fail())
{
    perror("Level_1.txt");
}
while (input_file >> _level)
{
    lvl.GetlevelData().push_back(_level);
}


}
```

it doesnt work it prints nothing, even though i added '&' 
the result is same when i try it with 'push_back' method in Level.h
Here is int main() just in case:

```
int main()
{
File f;
Level lvl;
f.LoadLevel();
lvl.PrintLevel();
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

And PrintLevel() in Level.cpp:

```
void Level::PrintLevel()
{
for (int i = 0; i < _level_data.size(); i++)
{
    cout << _level_data[i] << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: You call `f.LoadLevel();`  but the `f` does not know anything about `lvl` defined in `main()`, so why should there be anything inside of the `_level_data`  that is inside of that `lvl`? Where is the obviously different instance `lvl` inside of your `File` defined?

Comment: @t.niese because I set '_level_data' 's value in OpenLevel() by using GetLevelData().pushback(_level)

Comment: In your `main()` you show here `lvl` is a new instance of `Level`  that is not used anywhere, so calling `lvl.PrintLevel`  in the main will not show anything because its `_level_data`  is empty.

Comment: @t.niese Oooh right!!! what should i do ?

Comment: @belkipAndroidness -- `what should i do ?` -- Why did you choose to do things in this way, where you have two different classes, `File` and `Level`? (it doesn't matter if one class "looks like" the other, they're different).  What is / was the goal / purpose?  It's *your* design, you need to figure out what you really intended to do.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  well Im studying 'classes' and tried doing and Rogue-like challange so I wanted to use as much classes as possible

Comment: @belkipAndroidness Voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will try putting Level loop in the Level.cpp file that would probably fix it

Answer (score 0):

The `GetlevelData` function returns its vector *by value* which means a whole new copy of it is created. Anything you push into that vector will be lost when the copy goes out of scope (which happens when the expression `Lvl.GetLevelData().pushback(_level)` is done).

You should return it *by reference* instead:

```
vector<string>& GetlevelData(){ return _level_data; }
//            ^
//            |
// Return by reference
```

Comment: @belkipAndroidness You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<string>GetlevelData()`  returns a copy of the vector and not a reference to it.

So your `Lvl.GetLevelData().push_back(_level);` returns a copy adds data to the vector and then deletes that copy again. So you add it to a vector that will be immediately be deleted again.

You would need to return it either by reference:

```
vector<string>& GetlevelData(){ return _level_data; }
```

Or write a method to push back the data:

```
void push_back( const std::string &string) { 
   _level_data.push_back(string);
}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be const?

Comment: @belkipAndroidness Passing `string` as reference avoids an additional copy, but this would allow you to modify the string inside of you `push_back`. But because you don't want to modify that `string` in there you add a `const`, that way you or somewhere else using your code, can be sure that the `string` is not modified when it is passed to the `push_back`, without the need to look inside of the definition of your method.

Comment: thanks for the explaination, but both methods don't seem to work :/

Comment: @belkipAndroidness - *but both methods don't seem to work :/* -- Please explain what is meant by "don't seem to work".  It is obvious that you were returning a copy, and the fix to that problem is to return a reference.

Comment: @belkipAndroidness then the error is somewhere else in your code and you need to be more specific because this simple example works on [ideone](https://ideone.com/OwQF62)

Comment: @belkipAndroidness And here is proof that your original code did the wrong thing, [just as you described](http://ideone.com/3fXgil).  See, no output when a copy is returned.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  I Edited my question